# subtraction of two loc values in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two value found from the following analysis:

```
v1= dd['y'].loc[dd['localtime']==dd['localtime'].max()]

v2= dd['y'].loc[dd['localtime']==dd['localtime'].min()]
```

the value is in the form:

> ```
> v1
> 4906    4344.22552
> Name: y, dtype: float64
>
> v2
> 4785    5400.39864
> Name: y, dtype: float64
> ```

How can I get the differce of this two value `(v2-v1)` as `(5400.39864 - 4344.22552)`?

Answer (score 0):

If assigning v3 = v2 - v1 doesn't work, make sure they are of the same object type. However, it looks like you're trying to find a time difference, in which case I would look at Panda's inbuilt [Time Delta](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) functions

Comment: Thanks. It was the object type problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
v1 = pd.Series(4344.22552, index=[4906], name='y')
print (v1)
4906    4344.22552
Name: y, dtype: float64

v2 = pd.Series(5400.39864, index=[4785], name='y')
print (v2)
4785    5400.39864
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

Substract values converted to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) - get arrays with `length=1`, so select by `[0]`:

```
print (v2.values[0] - v1.values[0])
1056.17312

print ((v2.values - v1.values)[0])
1056.17312
```

Or select first value of `v1` and `v2` by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
print (v2.iat[0] - v1.iat[0])
1056.17312
```

But I think better is use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and 
[`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
v1 = dd.loc[dd['localtime'].idxmax(), 'y']
v2=  dd.loc[dd['localtime'].idxmin(), 'y']
```

Sample:

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'localtime':[1,2,3,5],
                   'y':[5400.39864,2000,3000,4344.22552]}, 
                  index=[4785,4786,4788,4906])

print (dd)
      localtime           y
4785          1  5400.39864
4786          2  2000.00000
4788          3  3000.00000
4906          5  4344.22552

v1 = dd.loc[dd['localtime'].idxmax(), 'y']
v2 = dd.loc[dd['localtime'].idxmin(), 'y']

print (v2 - v1)
1056.17312
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a nice suggestion. 
I think, I had the problem with the data type. 

I simply converted it to int. 
v1= int(dd['y'].loc[dd['localtime']==dd['localtime'].max()])
v2= int(dd['y'].loc[dd['localtime']==dd['localtime'].min()])

Print (v2-v1)